# Why does Chrome remove port number for localhost:80?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cors, localhost, port

I'm making a request from my frontend React application and running it on my server with localhost:80. When viewing the request and header in the browser, Chrome automatically removes the port number which causes a CORS error. Why does Chrome strip out this port number? What are best practices in this scenario? I've simply changed the port from 80 to 8080 and that resolved the issue.

I've set the headers to Access-Control-Allow-Origin for all types of HTTP requests and this did not seem to resolve the issue. This also led me to believe that the port being absent on the request header was the root cause of the issue (which is why I changed it from 80 to 8080).

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // If needed
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); // If needed
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
}
```

not working port here

```
app.listen(80, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log(

      =====================================================
      -> Server (${chalk.bgBlue('Hot reload')})  (running) on ${chalk.green(
      'localhost',
    )}:${chalk.green('80')}
      =====================================================
    ,
  );
```

^^this one was not working and chrome removed the port in the URL

changed port here

```
app.listen(8080, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log(

      =====================================================
      -> Server (${chalk.bgBlue('Hot reload')})  (running) on ${chalk.green(
      'localhost',
    )}:${chalk.green('8080')}
      =====================================================
    ,
  );
```

^^this one was working and chrome left the port in the URL

I was expecting CORS to allow the requests to go through even when no port was specified but this did not happen. I'm running a node.js server, utilizing graphql for my backend, react framework for my front end, and cors version is "cors": "^2.8.4"

Comment: To be transparent, I've not tested other browsers to see if the same behavior persists. I'm operating under the assumption this is a chrome only issue but I have not verified yet.

Comment: You’re operating under the wrong assumption. All browsers behave the same way for this. Browsers don’t “strip out” the port number from the origin value or URL if the port is 80 and the protocol is http. Browsers just don’t show the port number in some places in the UI in that case — because if they did, they would be showing it all the time for most every http site, since the vast majority of web sites are served from port 80.

Comment: The cause of whatever problem you’ve had is not due to Chrome “stripping out” port 80 from the origin value or URL. But it’s hard to know what the real problem might actually be, because the question as currently written doesn’t state the details of the problem. You say, *“Chrome automatically removes the port number which causes a CORS error”*. What is the exact CORS error? You say, “I was expecting CORS to allow the requests to go through even when no port was specified but this did not happen”*. So exactly what happens instead?

Comment: @sideshowbarker the error logged in the console is as follows: Access to fetch at 'https://api-dev.fliptrx.com/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: The reason I concluded it was the browser stripping the port number out is because  of the error message only displaying the origin as `localhost` as opposed to `localhost:80`

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is the default port already used by the world wide web (www). Is there a reason that this port number needs to be specifically used (for local development im guessing)?

Comment: No, there's no particular reason. I'm working with an inherited code base from an offshore team and this was one issue I was encountering. I don't know if this sufficiently answers why Chrome strips out the port number though. Does chrome restrict that port because it's used by the "world wide web"?

Comment: @rweber87 Im not 100% sure either I just know it uses this port to perform HTTP requesting. So, I assume that this may have something to do with it. You could also try port 443 for HTTPS and see if you run into similar issues.

Comment: I've gone ahead and switched the port to 8080 (see example above) which kept the report in the request header and resolved the issue.